# Data is not really storing database in nhibernate

Tags: nhibernate

I am writing a simple program using nhibernate
Program.cs

```
  using System;
  using System.Collections.Generic;
  using System.Linq;
  using System.Text;
  using NHibernate;
  using NHibernate.Cfg;
  using System.Data.SqlServerCe;
  using NHibernate.ByteCode.LinFu;


  namespace FirstSolution
  {
    class Program
  {
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Product p = new Product();
        p.id = "padu";
        p.name = "Sayan";
        p.category = "Bogus";
        Configuration cfg = new Configuration();
        cfg.AddXmlFile("C:/Users/win7/Documents/Visual Studio 2008/Projects/FirstSolution/FirstSolution/Product.hbm.xml");
        try
        {
            using (ISessionFactory factory = cfg.BuildSessionFactory())
            {
                using (ISession session = factory.OpenSession())
                {
                    using (ITransaction transaction = session.BeginTransaction())
                    {

                        // Tell NHibernate that this object should be saved
                        session.Save(p);

                        // commit all of the changes to the DB and close the ISession
                        session.Flush();
                        transaction.Commit();
                        session.Close();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
        string s;
        s = Console.ReadLine();

       }
       }
       }
```

App.config

```
      <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
      <configuration>
      <configSections>
       <section name="hibernate-configuration"
         type="NHibernate.Cfg.ConfigurationSectionHandler, NHibernate" />
       </configSections>
      <connectionStrings>
      <add name="FirstSolution.Properties.Settings.Database1ConnectionString"
         connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|    \Database1.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True"
       providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
      </connectionStrings>
      <hibernate-configuration xmlns="urn:nhibernate-configuration-2.2">
       <session-factory>
      <property          name="connection.provider">NHibernate.Connection.DriverConnectionProvider</property>
  <property name="dialect">NHibernate.Dialect.MsSqlCeDialect</property>
    <property name="connection.driver_class">NHibernate.Driver.SqlClientDriver</property>
    <property name="proxyfactory.factory_class">
         NHibernate.ByteCode.LinFu.ProxyFactoryFactory, NHibernate.ByteCode.LinFu
     </property>
     <property name="connection.connection_string">Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;   AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|Database1.mdf;Integrated Security=true;User Instance=true;</property>
     <property name="show_sql">true</property>
     <mapping assembly="FirstSolution"/>
     </session-factory>
     </hibernate-configuration>
    </configuration>
```

Product.hbm.xml

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
    <hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2" namespace="FirstSolution"     assembly="FirstSolution">
    <class name="Product" table="UserTable" lazy="false">
    <id name="id" column="id" type="String" length="10">
    <generator class="assigned"/>
    </id>
    <property name="name" column="name" type="String" length="10"/>
   <property name="category" column="category" type="String" length="10"/>
   </class>
   </hibernate-mapping>
```

Product.cs

```
   using System;
   using System.Collections.Generic;
   using System.Linq;
   using System.Text;

   namespace FirstSolution
   {
    public class Product
    {
    public String id { get; set; }
    public String name { get; set; }
    public String category { get; set; }

    }
    }
```

Program is running without any exception. Generated sql is showing on console. But no data is saved in UserTable of Database1.mdf

Comment: what is : |DataDirectory|    \Database1.mdf

Answer (score 1):

Database1.mdf is being copied to the /bin/Debug folder when the application is built and the data is saved there.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm. I'm surprised that you don't get exceptions. The Product class must have virtual properties, otherwise it won't work.

Also, I see you're using the MsSqlCeDialect. I haven't used SqlExpress but SqlExpress != SqlCe. Trying using MsSql2005Dialect or MsSql2005Dialect.

Comment: With `lazy="false"`, no need to have virtual properties. Virtual properties are required only when  NHibernate needs to proxify the entities. Without lazy loading, it does not need to. About te cpnnection string, it seems he really wants to use MsSQL CE, so that would be just the `Data Source` property which is a trash needing to be removed.